Milk Thistle (Silybin) and it's effect on drug metabolism
I am looking at giving our senior dog something like Denamarin, a liver supplement, which contains an active part of an extract from milk thistle called Silybin, to aid in improving liver health.
I will of course talk to our vet before doing so, but am I correct from my reading that this can inhibit the metabolism of a range of drugs, because of it's effect on the CYP3A4 and CYP2C9 enzymes?
To my understanding CYP3A4 is used by a lot of drugs, and particularly prednisone, and if it is inhibited by Silybin, the drug cannot be converted to its active form, prednisolone, and if given consistently, can build up in the body?
We have Pred-X on hand, which we give on the off chance our dog gets stung by a bee (she is allergic), to give us time to get to the vet - however, to my understanding this is the activated form, prednisolone.
Given it's already the active form, this doesn't present a major issue with making sure it works, and in time, however, if I am correct, the body still needs to metabolise it so that it's broken down for elimination?
On that, if I am also correct, whilst CYP3A4 would be the primary enzyme to do this, there are also multiple backup systems for processing drugs, and the drug elimination process doesn't completely stop; it just becomes slower and relies more on alternative pathways?
Assuming this is all true, in this example scenario it wouldn't present much of an issue, as it was a one off dose of Pred-X, in it's already active state, and it will be broken down by the body and eliminated, just at a slower rate.
Again, assuming this is all true, my main concern then becomes if we need to give other drugs. To my understanding, I believe the half-life of Silybin is around 6 hours, however the effects can last 3-7 days whilst the enzymes recover.
Denamarin seems to use a special formulation, silybin-phosphatidylcholine complex, which is covered in this study, run by the company behind it.
The study showed that:

The phosphatidylcholine complex dramatically increased absorption,
creating what the paper described as a 3-4.4 fold increase in
bioavailability
Helps it get into the bloodstream more effectively
Dogs given the phosphatidylcholine complex showed significantly higher blood levels compared to regular silymarin extract
The complex achieved peak concentrations (Cmax) of about 1310 ng/mL
Regular silymarin extract only reached peak concentrations of about 472 ng/mL
The overall exposure (AUC) was about 3 times higher with the complex
The complex seems to maintain therapeutic levels longer than standard milk thistle extract, though it still follows a similar elimination pattern through the liver.

Now, whilst this sounds all good for the therapeutic effect, this raises increased concerns for the potential effects on the metabolism of other drugs.
However, I do note that, and I will be contacting Denamarin about this, but they state in their FAQ that:

Can Denamarin be used with other products?
Yes, your veterinarian may recommend combining Denamarin with other products, and/or dietary modifications. There are no known interactions of Denamarin with drugs or other supplements.

So, my questions are, do I have this all correct?

Should I be concerned about drug inhibition?
Could this potentially cause a build up in the body of drugs?
Does the body need to break down the drugs via the same enzymes for elimination?
Are there "backup systems/enzymes" available if the main enzymes are inhibited?
If stopping Silybin, do the enzymes need 3-7 days to recover?
Does it seem like Denamarin's formulation may make my concerns even more valid?


Ask your vet. Drug interaction and dietary supplements are within their field of expertise.

@keshlam As I said I will be talking to my vet, however I am after a sourced scientific based answer as a means of confirmation.

Good luck. Most of us here are amateurs. Free advice on the internet may not be worth more than you paid for it.

@keshlam Your dismissive response isn't appreciated. This isn't about "free advice" - this is about using a platform to ask a question that someone may have an answer to; I considered asking this on Biology Stack Exchange, but since it was about Pets, I thought it might be better here. If there was a place you could pay to get an answer to this question, I would have no problem doing so, and as such, I don't appreciate the implications you are throwing around.

Sorry. I meant it honestly, no implications. My guess would be that the biology stack would tell you that time to metabolize depends on the specific animal's condition, though they might be able to tell you more about the biochemistry of the supplement if there is enough detail in the study to determine that. Personally, I am paranoid about things labeled as supplements rather than medications, but this could be an exception, and I certainly can't blame someone with a sick pet for looking at every possibility.

@keshlam Ok, sorry if I seemed hostile, it just came across as me being called cheap and expecting free advice and I wasn't willing to pay for help.
Also thanks for your thoughts, and yep, certainly a lot of supplements to be weary of for sure - however in this instance there seems to be a lot of solid evidence about the effectiveness of Milk Thistle and its positive effects on the liver (at least in animals).
